# Accessing Sizzle methods via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

In the jQuery source it clearly says `jQuery.find = Sizzle;`

but when i try to access a particular Sizzle method the function doesn't exist. 
This is what the objects look like.

```
window.Sizzle   |   window.jQuery.find

.isXML          |   .isXML
.matches        |   .matches
.matchesSelector|   .matchesSelector
.contains       |   .contains
.attr           |   .attr
.error          |   .error
.uniqueSort     |   .uniqueSort
.getText        |   .getText
.selectors      |   .selectors
.tokenize       |   
.compile        |   
.select         |   
.support        |   
.setDocument    |   
                |   .find
                |   .filter
```

I don't understand why the jquery team would overwrite/delete the methods. 
Is there a way of accessing these missing functions or do I have to download the sizzle library ?
The method I need it tokenize.

[jquery source](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js) 

[Sizzlejs source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/sizzle/master/src/sizzle.js)

Many Thanks

Comment: If `window.Sizzle`, doesn't that mean the library is already downloaded?

Comment: May be you should take a look at the migrate plugin as suggested by jquery team.

Comment: @Anthony Sorry yea, I loaded it just for comparison. Sizzle is only available to the jquery object because its in a closure so it is not globally accessible.

Comment: @Jai This is not a version issue. when I said it was removed I mean it exists in the sizzle object but not in the $.find object. I did not mean that the methods  once existed in a previous version of jQuery and deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can use $.find.tokenize - see issue https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/242

Comment: $.find.tokenize does exist in newer version of jquery

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that issue but i assumed it was a problem with jquery as when i was using sizzle the methods were accessible. I was using a version of jquery that used the older verion of the sizzle library before that commit.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to access Sizzle methods from jQuery for whatever reason...

In jQuery source we have...

```
jQuery.find = Sizzle;
```

So all Sizzle methods can be accessed from `jQuery.find`